# Is there any way to restrict the plots in one grapgh?

Tags: matlab, graph, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot several signals in one graph and i would like to restrict them and sort of minimize it so all my signals will be clear (more or less).
I have no idea how to do it. I'm adding an image so what i need to do will be clearer.
[image: This is how i want my graph to look]

My data changes but in general it's the mean intensity of each column of a certain area in an intensity image.I tried to do it like with the same idea as you but i don't get the right plot as i wanted.  A is the relevant matrix,b is the matrix with shifted values:

```
for i=1:20
b(i,:)=A(i,:)+(100*i);
plot(b(i,:))
hold on
end
```

I will  also add 2 images: one is the plot of all the 20 signals that i get and the other one is the plot of only the first signal. I don't understand why do they look so different.
[image: This is how one signal looks]
[image: This is how all the 20 signal look when i plot them together]

Comment: Give this a try: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2PXYMC/?product=SL&solution=1-2PXYMC

Comment: @Dan My understanding is that the OP wants to stagger the plots on the `y` axis so that they don't overlap, rather than create breaks on the `x` axis.

Comment: @am304 switch all the X for Y is trivial. And staggering and breaks is kind of the same principle in terms of overlaying multiple graphs so that they look like a single graph. Then just change the ticklabels instead of the ticks themselves

Comment: @Dan But in each time i can have several Y values that are the same so i didn't understand so much how it can work?

Comment: @Maayan why not just use subplot?

Comment: Because my boss wants them all in the same graph so he can see it clearer.

Comment: You want to place all signals on same plot but without getting overlap ? If yes, just shift them with a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that :

```
x = [1:100]; %Distance 1 to 100
y = F(x) % Your first function (signal)
y2 = 0.5*G(x) % Your second function (signal)

plot(x,y,x,y2); % plot both function in a single plot.

hleg1 = legend('Intensity t1,'Intensity t27');
```

So you have your signal at intensity t27 half cut for each value ( 0.5 ), so it shift down.

Comment: Maybe you will need to search for good scalar depending on your signals. But this is easy way and not really automatic way to do it.

Comment: Yes, you have the value of min/max to get biggest signal. But, it hard to eval the scalar needed to display well the signal. Maybe you need to rescale with 1/30000 to be at the right place on your graph. This exemple need more informations on data and a bit of work by the user to use it well.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau I edited my question and added new information

Comment: Sorry, didn't use the right word. You need to scale it and not to shift it. So multiply by a scalar. Ex : 2 and 4, rescale with 1/2 and 1/4 will be 1, but the alpha is different, so your render will be near 1 for both. You have to found good scalar matching your signal.